# Calculating age from dob in PostgreSQL using trigger

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to calculate the age of a person when a record is inserted or updated in table `staff` but somehow the below trigger function does not work:

```
create or replace function Age() 
returns trigger as $body$
declare
dob1 date;
age1 integer;
BEGIN
select dob into dob1 from staff; 
select age(current_date,dob) into age1;
update staff set age=age1;
END; $body$ language plpgsql;

create trigger trig_age
before insert or update on staff
FOR EACH ROW
execute procedure age();
```

I'm not sure about this above code. I want a trigger to calculate and insert the AGE when inserting DOB in some table

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: i have a table named staff with attributes like staff_id,staff_name,dob,age. whenever i insert dob into staff table it should automatically calculates age and should insert into age column

Comment: There's a built-in function named `age`, so you should probably prefer a different name...

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the name of the trigger function may not be the most appropriate. There is already an overloaded regular function by that name and while the parameters differ and PostgreSQL will therefore accept it, you might confuse whomever has to work with your code.

Otherwise you are not far off. The principal change is that you should not call an `UPDATE` in a trigger function for the same table that the trigger is fired for: you may get an infinite loop. Just use assignments to the `NEW` implicit parameter. Since you obviously want the age in years of a person, you should get that specific `date_part()` into field `age`.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION age_in_years() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $body$
BEGIN
  NEW.age := date_part('year', CURRENT_TIME - NEW.dob::timestamp);
  RETURN NEW; -- or the insert or update would fail
END; 
$body$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Setting the values in the `NEW` parameter and returning that parameter at the end of the function will change the values that will be inserted or updated into the table.

However, a person's age may change in between updates so you are probably better off dropping the column `age` from table `staff` (and thus also the trigger) and then creating a view that calculates the `age` whenever that view is accessed:

```
CREATE VIEW staff_today AS 
  SELECT *, date_part('year', CURRENT_TIME - dob::timestamp) AS age
  FROM staff;
```

Like so you will always get the correct age.

Comment: Alternatively just use the `age()` function

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name The function age() gives an interval while the age column in the OP staff table is obviously an integer. How old are you? 32 years 7 months and 2 days? Or just 32?

Comment: Thank you so much patrick.lemme try and revert you asap.

Comment: I'm not getting the result. error in 'year'

Comment: I got error like this while executing view.ERROR: function date_part(unknown, integer) does not exist
SQL state: 42883
Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
Character: 44

Comment: Your `dob` field is obviously not a `timestamp`, although that was not clear from your questions (you should always include table definitions). See updated answer.